# How to make children 100% height of their flexbox parent without adding a 100% height to each child

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a row with nested columns on my website which has bootstrap 3. The `.column` class has the background. I want the background color to fill the full height without changing the HTML.

If I add `height: 100%;` to the nested row, bootstrap col and to their column class I get the result I want, but is it possible to write this easier?

Here is my code

https://codepen.io/Insane415/pen/rZWYOE

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row sub-heading">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
         <div class="column">
            Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum <br>Break
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
         <div class="row sub-heading full-height">
            <div class="col-xs-4 full-height">
               <div class="column full-height"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
               <div class="column"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
               <div class="column"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

.sub-heading {
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  background: #fce6cc;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 -13px;
  min-height: 30px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.full-height {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: You can also use `.full-height { height: 100vh;}`  instead of `.full-height { height:100%;}`

Comment: 100% height of what? If you don't define a height of the container (and any parents upward) then any child can't know how tall it's supposed to be.

Comment: CSS flexbox can use `flex: 1` to let child tags to fill a existing space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without changing HTML:

```css
.sub-heading {
  height: 100%;
}

.sub-heading > div {
  background: pink;
}

.column {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 -13px;
  min-height: 30px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .sub-heading {
    display: flex;
  }
  
  .sub-heading > div {
    border-left: 5px solid #fff;
    border-right: 15px solid #fff;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
   <div class="row sub-heading">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
         <div class="column">
            Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum <br>Break
         </div>
      </div>
      
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
         <div class="row sub-heading full-height">
            <div class="col-xs-4 full-height">
               <div class="column full-height"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
               <div class="column"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
               <div class="column"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

as per my understanding i shared the snippet , i  hope it will helps u

```css
  .sub-heading {
                display: flex;
                    position: relative;
                    min-height: 100%;
                    border: 1px solid #eee;
              }
              
              .column {
                background: #fce6cc;
                position: relative;
                border:1px solid #333;
                margin: 0 -13px;
                min-height: 30px;
                padding: 0 15px;
                display: -webkit-box;
                display: -ms-flexbox;
                display: flex;
                -webkit-box-align: center;
                -ms-flex-align: center;
                align-items: center;
                -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
              }
              
              .sub-heading .column{
                min-height: 100%;
              }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row sub-heading">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
          <div class="column">
            Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum <br>Break
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
          <div class="row sub-heading">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
              <div class="column"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
              <div class="column"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
              <div class="column"> </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you run the snippet and saw the result ?

Comment: yes  i have run the snippet and saw the result . i  regret if i have understood the  question wrong , it is about how to get equal height for children  , i exactly did that i just added border to show they are in equal height , if your worried about width  , the fiddle which has been shared already using bootstrap so it will automatically be taken care of